# How does the roTextureManager image cache behave?

Tags: roku, brightscript

Does the roTextureManager clear or replace bitmaps in its cache automatically when it sees that it is running out of memory? I cannot seem to find any good answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, supposedly that is the purpose of `roTextureManager`, although the behavior is undocumented (go figure!).

See this thread http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=69730#p451528 for discussion and some assurance.

Comment: Thank you for that link. I guess i'll just have to test the edge cases and confirm.

Comment: Hi Karim - I'm getting into roku more heavily and would like to find out if you learned anything more about the rotexturemanager's caching behavior because I have the same question

Comment: Hi @JoeT what i have learnt about texture manager is very little. I did more and more tests and it got worse and worse. If you are caching anything with the texture manage, it will not tell you when memory is not available, it just fails next bitmap creation. Any bitmaps creation fails and you will have to purge it. I wrote some ind of framework maybe it will be of use to you https://github.com/kaayr1m/roku-framework https://github.com/kaayr1m/roku-framework-example